# Displaying non Roman characters in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, utf-8, meizu-mx4

Not sure whether someone already asked this question before, but I failed to get any in AskUbuntu search and on google search.

I bought a Ubuntu Edition Meizu phone recently. But it is not displaying UTF-8 (non English, non European) characters. It looks more like an Ubuntu phone specific issue, as displaying characters for different languages failed from multiple apps (*webbrowser* and *dekko* were tested so far). I couldn't find any specific instruction on how to resolve the issue.

*So would really appreciate if someone can help me displaying non-Roman characters on Ubuntu Touch.*

Comment: Yep, confirm that Indian is displayed as squares in the web browser on current version. As an example, use the name of the author of the question: http://www.indiachildnames.com/name.aspx?name=Tuhin I'll try to find something in the settings.

Comment: The possible option is to enable write mode for the filesystem and install the `ttf-indic-fonts-core` package using `apt-get`. If you can be more precise about the language, we can be more precise about the package. Maybe someone else can come up with better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the goal is to get additional fonts into the `~/.fonts` directory.

For example, the fonts from the `ttf-indic-fonts-core` package (http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/ttf-indic-fonts-core).

Install the Terminal app on the phone or connect to the phone via ssh or adb.

Create the `~/.fonts` directory:

```
mkdir -p ~/.fonts
```

Get the package (select other mirror from http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/ttf-indic-fonts-core if necessary):

```
wget http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/ttf-indic-fonts/ttf-indic-fonts-core_0.5.14ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Extract the package into temporary `ttf` directory:

```
dpkg -x ttf-indic-fonts-core_0.5.14ubuntu1_all.deb ~/ttf
```

Move fonts into `~/.fonts`:

```
mv ~/ttf/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ ~/.fonts
```

Remove temporary directory:

```
rm -r ~/ttf
```

Close and reopen the browser.

Tested in web browser on BQ phone with text তূহীন; તૂહીન; തൂഹീന; తూహీన; ತೂಹೀನ; தூஹீந. But for this one: ਤੂਹੀਨ, there is some other package needed.

(to figure out which package, I use Ubuntu desktop and gradually remove font packages until Firefox stops rendering the desirable text)

Comment: Thank Velkan, It just worked like a charm. I love my ubuntu phone more!!